# TOPMOST(SetWindowPos(, HWND_TOPMOST, ..)) does NOT work on IE9 or Vista/Win7?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, activex, topmost

For some special needs, I've coded an ActiveX control(dll) making the IE browser window containing it the TOPMOST window.

```
::SetWindowPos(pWndWb, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOSIZE|SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

The only problem is that this does not work well when I test on IE9 loading those control and html from online(remote) server.
That works well when I load them from a local directory of test pc even if I test on IE9. Of course, that always works well on IE8/WinXP even when I load them from online(remote) server.

I've read several posts concerning similar issues and tried given tips, but the problem remains unchanged.

For sure, I tried followings plus above, too:

```
::SetForegroundWindow(pWndWb);
::SetActiveWindow(pWndWb);
```